# Azure DevOps YAML CI and CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have separate yaml pipelines for CI and CD in Azure DevOps Services.
CI pipeline will publish an artifact to a file share location. \fileshare\project

[image]

[image]

And in the CD pipeline I am using the CI pipeline as resource so that I can deploy the artifact produced from the CI pipeline.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: POC_pipeline # identifier for the pipeline resource
    source: CI-pipeline_YAML # source pipeline definition name
```

My question is how can I download this artifact and what's the pre-defined variable name to get the path of the published artifact from CI-pipeline.

I tried using but it doesn't download anything, this only works when I push the artifact to Azure DevOps.

```
steps:
    - download: POC_pipeline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `download` task cannot download artifacts that published to a file share. I can reproduce the same issue. You can [report this problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click **Report a problem** and choose **Azure devops**) to Microsoft development team.

As workaround, you can use [Download Fileshare Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-fileshare-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to download fileshare artifacts.

```
- task: DownloadFileshareArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        filesharePath:  '\fileshare\project'
        artifactName: artifactName
        downloadPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

The artifacts will be downloaded to folder specified in `downloadPath`. In above example you will find the artifacts in  `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/artifactName` (ie.  `C:\agent\_work\2\a\artifactName`)

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to find more predefined variables.

You can also use [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) to download the fileshare artifacts. You need to specify the `source` as `specific`, and other `project`, `pipeline`,`runVersion` attributes. See below:

```
 - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        source: specific
        project: yourProjectName
        pipeline: CI-pipeline_YAML
        runVersion: latest
        path: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

The artifacts will be downloaded to folder specified in `path`.

Noted: you need to run your pipeline on self-hosted agents which can access the file share.(It will fail with error `Unable to read directory \fileshare\project" on cloud agents).